# Does Kafka-node has similar config as 'max.poll.records' options in consumer writing in java?

Tags: kafka-node

Recently I am writing some coding under nodeJS using Kafka-node module, and I want to control max poll numbers for each consume. From most of the blogs I can find the solution in java using 'max.poll.records' but hard to find one for nodeJS.

Anyone can help?